# How to get all values smaller than a given key in a BST?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Hello I am implementing a binary search tree. I have to find all the elements smaller than a given key applying a binary search:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node* right;
    node* left;
};

class binTree {
public:
    binTree();
    ~binTree();

    void insert(node**, int);
    void inOrder(node**)const;
    void preOrder(node**)const;
    void postOrder(node**)const;
    void delTree();

    node* search(node**, int)const;
    void search_less(node**, int)const;
};

binTree::binTree() {

}

binTree::~binTree() {

}

void binTree::insert(node** root, int data) {
    node* tmp = *root;
    if (!tmp) {
        tmp = new node;
        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->right = NULL;
        tmp->left = NULL;
        *root = tmp;
        return;
    }

    if (data < tmp->data)
        insert(&tmp->left, data);
    else
        insert(&tmp->right, data);
}

void binTree::preOrder(node** root)const {
    node* tmp = *root;
    if (tmp) {
        cout << tmp->data << endl;
        preOrder(&tmp->left);
        preOrder(&tmp->right);
    }
}

void binTree::inOrder(node** root)const {
    node* tmp = *root;
    if (tmp) {
        inOrder(&tmp->left);
        cout << tmp->data << endl;
        inOrder(&tmp->right);
    }
}

void binTree::postOrder(node** root)const {
    node* tmp = *root;
    if (tmp) {
        postOrder(&tmp->left);
        postOrder(&tmp->right);
        cout << tmp->data << endl;
    }
}

node* binTree::search(node** root, int data)const {
    node* tmp = *root;
    if (tmp) {
        if (data == tmp->data) {
            cout << "found!" << endl;
            return tmp;
        }
        else
            if (data < tmp->data)
                search(&tmp->left, data);
            else
                search(&tmp->right, data);
    }

    cout << data << ": not found in tree!" << endl;
    return NULL;
}

void binTree::search_less(node** root, int key)const
{
    node* tmp = *root;
    tmp = search(root, key);

}

int main()
{

    node* root = NULL;
    binTree bt;
    bt.insert(&root, 42000);
    bt.insert(&root, 41000);
    bt.insert(&root, 45000);
    bt.insert(&root, 47000);
    bt.insert(&root, 42500);
    bt.insert(&root, 43000);
    bt.insert(&root, 44000);
    bt.insert(&root, 40000);
    bt.insert(&root, 10000);
    bt.insert(&root, 20000);
    bt.insert(&root, 30000);

    bt.search_less(&root, 42000); // I want to get values smaller than 42000

}
```

- I've tried too much but couldn't figure it out. I want to print all the values below the key entered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an accumulator `std::vector<T>`
2. Set root node as current node
3. If current node is `nullptr`, go to 6 (you're done)
4. If current node is >= search value, set left node as current node and go to 3
5. If current node is < search value, accumulate this value and accumulate the entire subtree of the left node. Set right node as current node and go to 3
6. Return the accumulator

Accumulating the entire left node should be its own function (`accumulate_entire_tree` or something like that). The recursive function should be steps 3-5. Steps 1-6 are the entire wrapper function. In the end you get three functions:

1. `std::vector<int> search_less_than(const Node& root, int key) const`
2. `void accumulate_less_than(const Node* root, int key, std::vector<int>& accumulator) const`
3. `void accumulate_entire_tree(const Node* root, std::vector<int>& accumulator) const`

Make the last two functions private since they're more implementation details than interface.

Comment: You can even have your accumulator ordered in increasing value if you write your `accumulate_entire_tree` function correctly and if for step 5 you accumulate the left subtree before accumulating the current value. I recommend this since it adds no extra overhead and sorted values are usually good.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something similar to your `search` function:

```cpp
void binTree::search_less(node** root, int data) const {
    node* tmp = *root;
    if (tmp) {
        if (data > tmp->data) {
            search_less(&tmp->left, data);
            cout << tmp->data << endl;
            search_less(&tmp->right, data);
        } else {
            search_less(&tmp->left, data);
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2BkgEBt/mCr54x7Nx6t2ntkBi4fdnq9mX9omDnbOqnjjggOxqgi1uGoVAEPP0YGg5iTxmpzXpghGHxzDwEmbQ4hbh2pvBUGYQMBgc8%2BI/fVOQz9Xm97AAdzTItIRmT8AFoNhBLIAP3MEY1%2BcC/igjZ4URIF5hvBwAFVrGsMC/wvaCPGwLEsOvGY8IIoj/jvB94M/Oi/hWAhBloMD8VnElkL%2BZ9X1g5grx0CCSJgg8hVjFDVzcdcpAANjQsiKJ1IT9VTZQlF/f5ZPVRTlOwDCkTUySUwHXiFy7ZdXUwENLVPCNN23BssJ/aS01hf9sNve9tzAgSIE/b9HRQtADEonR5lEwyhJE6KZisVgWJmWz7IgAzxJUzBsQ0jzITS81Q0ynxSKMhEkTyvivh47jp3nEtrI7Ox0sc2E/L1KM3NCzyxMvHyGP8pDIUC4Kp3y3TaHSkqyooqqUL%2BcLIoS2KD3ihZEu0ZLhoWlqistGb0IqvUuIsuq5yspcOz8epWutZzOp9bqTwxPr4MGx8PNGi8Qp0v4buDfaMskJSsvInKTp2lCAemkHDOMyGeshJb1pisG4uihKktO2qzt2RzF15EclDLbM2oe3cgXUrrxuqgnvKoj6ApfIKftphaARZjHrx81asl%2BiawoGZaNqkSQaAMbR3zF1HNvQbakYWtiOL6lLzuqyEtMwP7wMC7m0dKiT%2BZ1jmSazYHQcN7LsVM42oY5xLWG0wWHbN8sLfh47bcPHH6uR4XZf1hKxZAN4gQl7QVQg%2BlpckSRZex%2B3leIWhqPwwikPV/ZLqJ/kOzdytqwUDcOsphDDxmLqZXcunXoZm8mft76v3Z3aubWjY%2BrK9TW4d0ssyrc5i8O62d3L%2Ba%2B8rgPMY2vnhJn0TE8VlCC8HmsR/KzDvYnlDuMdpRe9dzNyzX4e4bB1Tx7VizISzvHeMBGYjGYOxk37Pta5hB74JojOeusqkn1qrOAIAAOj0vJEGpcZjcEkFseBO9AHgNVHJC20DuCcHgVsRBIDkFrjQQ%2BHU3AzBYJwWAiBBDtxEM%2BKQsCuCKGKXQZIEh2C6HkJQfpKBhCYEeFofbehHDIEKXQdwPh/92H4MYdw0RYjUwCMkVwqhMxMGyI8vI1BUilFwNUcAiRGjFFj14TouRYDV5F0oWPWBYiZgAHobEzAAJIzCAiIIERAZjAEwECOUbADDnBuM/Vg7BiAQQQCIGB2itiplTCjBecsFbRLUaY4%2Bhch4WJ1EYhB9xbH2KcS4vc7jPHeN8f4hQgTgmhPCVY%2BB9VuIjD6KwEAIwzAjFIKYEYWxWmoCaVFGQcgbgDCGAySQXhWkECaZ0nofQADW5hJCgIUh4GhnwzCfE4AADi2JwMwCldlCCadwVp7TOmkG6SMVpCgQBbFIOMjp9TSBwFgDARAKBUAXjwME8glA0DvOCSAYAABOSQpAqAfIIG4S5EBnATNaTybIABPJpnBWk/KMFoYMtBWCIruaQLAz9RDsBhbivAKx0hynOESzAAAPNIEVRgnMBMoIlbJnDEARXoLASKxnwiMFyvoNB6BMDYBwHg/BBDCFECgOQcghB4GcJcyAfRUA%2BBKKqJpkFIK3GwhIPpMhOCfAuakdIGgIBWCaKYbwVhKhxASIIG6URgj6HyHayIqrrXVESCkYoGRWjmsEEUNIqqyg5HdZ0T19Ryh%2BrqK0UNtrej9EGMMLgDSmktLaUSs5VL1kKUggpbgHjkDIBmAC0B8cIC4EICQOYIzvAzD0L8tw1avCTl6bIGQYyYVTNILMpZoCLCNJGIc0gvKSHppxWci5Vybmdoec8iASBhbMh3BQCAPyfAfK6JYfARBPUCsYCwQlnBgVATZT4Pl%2BzmlHIzU08YnBnGEAQDMLNOa80FqLSWyQHa7ldoQKsC0lAU2DtaSO65xyulNMndc25kyZkgG4J8UBHgFKSCBbA9ZnAAXrO4B4DwvAB0eCveOiD07v2Ac/WOk5E6SMwdIOS4gAQNDcCAA%3D)

Answer (score 0):

In case the Key is existing then it is straightforward: inside `search_less` use yur function `search` to find the key then pass its node to `inOrder` or `postOrder`...

If the you want to get values smaller than a non existing key: It is a bit tricky:

- If the key is smaller than the root node data then move leftward until data is smaller than the key or equal then pass that node to inOrder or postOrder.

  - If the key is greater than root then move rightward until a node with data is smaller than or equal to it then do the first step and print.

    ```
    void binTree::search_less(node** root, int data)const
    {
        node* tmp = *root;
        if (tmp && tmp->data < data)
            tmp = tmp->right;
        while (tmp && tmp->data >= data)
            tmp = tmp->left;
        inOrder(&tmp);

    }
    ```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some considerable time and effort to find this solution on my own:

```
void binTree::search_less(node** root, int key)const 
{
    node* tmp = *root;
    if(tmp)
    {
        search_less(&tmp->left, key);
        if(key <= tmp->data)
            return;
        search_less(&tmp->right, key);
        std::cout << tmp->data << ", ";   
     }
} 


int main() 
{

    node* root = NULL; 
    binTree bt; 
    bt.insert(&root, 42000); 
    bt.insert(&root, 41000); 
    bt.insert(&root, 45000); 
    bt.insert(&root, 47000); 
    bt.insert(&root, 42500);
    bt.insert(&root, 43000); 
    bt.insert(&root, 44000); 
    bt.insert(&root, 40000); 
    bt.insert(&root, 10000); 
    bt.insert(&root, 20000); 
    bt.insert(&root, 30000); 
    bt.search_less(&root, 37500);

    std::cout << "\nDone!\n";
}
```

The output:

```
30000, 20000, 10000,
Done!

[Process completed - press Enter]
```

- I walk left most through recursion until i get to the smallest value in the tree using the "inOrder" method because it get values sorted from small to big. then print it and walk right and check whether the data is greater than or equal to the key, in this case stop and return.
- Please tell me whether this is a correct and efficient solution?

Comment: If the current node's value is less than the key, then ALL nodes on the left branch of the current node are guaranteed to be less than the key as well. You can call your `inOrder` function on `&tmp->left` if this proves to be true.